# Download files using Shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to download a number of files which are as follows:

```
http://example.com/directory/file1.txt
http://example.com/directory/file2.txt
http://example.com/directory/file3.txt
http://example.com/directory/file4.txt
.
.
http://example.com/directory/file199.txt
http://example.com/directory/file200.txt
```

Can anyone help me with it using shell scripting? Here is what I'm using but it is downloading only the first file.

```
for i in {1..200}
do
exec wget http://example.com/directory/file$i.txt;
done
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
wget http://example.com/directory/file{1..200}.txt
```

should do it. That expands to `wget http://example.com/directory/file1.txt http://example.com/directory/file2.txt ...`.

Alternatively, your current code should work fine if you remove the call to `exec`, which is unnecessary and doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

Answer (score 2):

To download a list of files you can use `wget -i <file>` where  is a file name with a list of url to download.

For more details you can review the help page: `man wget`